# Replacing newline characters in Column A with contents from Column B

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[error am getting in the MS Excel 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L66gH.png) I have two Columns, The first row in column A has 5-10 paragraphs of text. First row in column B has some data separated by commas. I wanted to merge these two data in the columns into a new column.

I want to Merge the data from the second column into the first column data after every newline character. And the data in the second column are separated by newline characters.

How to do this using formulas or VBA scripts?

For Example

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AValue1 AValue2 AValue3 | Bvalue1 Bvalue2 | AValue1 Bvalue1 AValue2 Bvalue2 AValue3 |

if number of Values in B exceeds that of the Values in A, they can just be inserted one after another.

[Evaluation Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgkoz.png)

Comment: You can quickly create an array of strings using `Split` with the delimiter being `vbLf`. And then you can use `Replace` with `Count:=1`  to swap the first instance of `vbLf` in the other string, with the first element of the array (concatenate back the `vbLf`s).

Comment: Or a less janky method would be to create two arrays using `Split` with delimiter `vbLf`. And then create an empty third array with length being `Ubound + Ubound + 1`. Fill the third array with the first two arrays, and then `Join` with separator being `vbLf`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,TOCOL(VSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(A1,CHAR(10)),TEXTSPLIT(B1,CHAR(10))),3,1))
```

---

I believe the following would work in Excel 2021:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,SORTBY(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1&CHAR(10)&B1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))+1),SEQUENCE(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,CHAR(10),""))+1))&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

Comment: I am still so mad the only function I have on my work version is TEXTJOIN.  I am dying not having these to play with at work.

Comment: @ScottCraner, count your blessings too. My work upgraded from 2013 to 2016 last year! =)

Comment: Am getting Invalid Name Error. Mybad, Am using MS Office 2021. Any changes I should make to the code?

Comment: @masstamilan.im, I edited the answer to include an option for ms 2021.

Comment: that doesn't work too. Am still seeing a Invalid Name Error, Maybe because it has to do with the Column B values being urls??

Comment: Is this for Mac?

Comment: This is for Windows Only.

Comment: @masstamilan.im, the error would mean it doesn't recognize one of the functions being used but I don't see why unless you used wrong translations? They should all be available on windows excel 2021.

Comment: How would I accomplish the same in Google Sheets?. May be I can try in that. Sheets are consistent unlike MS Excel.

Comment: Or even a VBA script will work fine I think. The formulas for whatever is not working on MS Excel 2021. I tried changing Data, still the forumula doesn't work.

Comment: @masstamilan.im, have a look at the [file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmlmnAMqhNdLgP8jGbk-OAWFzA8sbA?e=MLjU6u). Might help you before you venture into other solutions.

Comment: I have added the image, where am getting this error, And I checked your link. It seems working. Is there any setting I need to change in order for this to work?

Comment: I think My excel sheet denomination is wrong. When I click them They are Mentioned as R1C1, etc. Are they right?? May be that is why this is not working??

Comment: Possibly @masstamilan.day, change that to normal notations in the settings. It's under options _> Formulas -> Notation option R1C1 needs to be unchecked.

Comment: I tried Evaluating the Steps , I have attached a picture for reference.

Comment: I have changed that, still getting the error. Btw, I don't want to move to Sheets,. I love working in Excel. Maybe a VBA script can be used??

Comment: @masstamilan.day, then you'd have to write a script. Either way, this formula should work. If you willing to do so, you can share your screen for me to have a look?

Comment: Thank you for your time buddy, I think I don't have the addins enabled for that formula to work.

Comment: Still, it's strange. All the used functions are available in Excel 2021 without any plugins whatsoever according to the documentation. Does 2021 require CSE entered formulas maybe?